# Spingboot Thymeleaf form passes null values into the controller

Tags: spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

could someone help me figure out why it is passing null values instead of actual names? The form has a input textbox for last name and fistname but I would only get null values when I access "authorRequest.getLastName() or authorRequest.getFirstName().

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class AuthorController {
private BooktownService __authorService = BooktownServiceFactory.getInstance();
private Model mod;
private String msg = "";
first endpoint, return a collection of authors
 @GetMapping("/booktown/list")
 public List<Author> returnAuthors() {
    return __authorService.getAuthors();
 }

@GetMapping("/booktown/list")
public String returnAuthors(Model model) {
    this.mod = model;
    Author auth= new Author();
    List<Author> auths =  __authorService.getAuthors();
    if(msg == ""){
        msg = "Listing page for Authors";
    }
    mod.addAttribute("authors", auths);
    mod.addAttribute("authorRequest", auth);
     mod.addAttribute("msg",msg);
    return "list_form";
}

// third endpoint, create an Author via POST
@PostMapping("/booktown/add")
public String createAuthor(@ModelAttribute("authorRequest") Author authorRequest) {
    __authorService.createAuthor(authorRequest.getLastName(), authorRequest.getFirstName());
    msg = "Added Author" + authorRequest.getFirstName() + " " + authorRequest.getLastName();
    return "redirect:/booktown/list";
}

// Sixth endpoint: DELETE
@GetMapping("/booktown/delete")
public String deleteAuthor(@RequestParam Integer id) {
    // returns a boolean
    __authorService.deleteAuthor(id);
    msg = "Deleted Author " + id;
    System.out.println("deleted");
    return "redirect:/booktown/list";
}
```

}

**Html:**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/booktown/add}" th:object="${authorRequest}" method="post">
<p>Last name: <input type="text" th:field="*{__lastName}" /></p>
<p>First name: <input type="text" th:field="*{__firstName}" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

**Author.java:**
package com.booktown.booktownservice;

```
public class Author {
    public Author(){}
    public Author(int id, String lname, String fname) {
        __id = id;
        __lastName  = lname;
        __firstName = fname;
    }
    public int getAuthorID() {
        return __id;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return __lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return __firstName;
    }

    public int get__id() {
        return __id;
    }
    public String get__lastName() {
        return __lastName;
    }
    public String get__firstName() {
        return __firstName;
    }

    private int    __id;
    private String __lastName;
    private String __firstName;
}
```

Comment: you have a no-args constructor, but no setters in you `Author` class, so if Thymeleaf uses this constructor there's no way to set these attributes to class fields - try to create setters. Also this might be the problem with naming - fields starting with underscores and "strange" getters names. So I suggest to rename fields (to remove underscores at the beginning) and  to follow naming convention for getters and setters

Comment: It might be the latter because I inserted setters not long after and it still gave me null values. I ended up ditching @ModelAttribute and used "public String createAuthor(String firstName, String lastName)" instead.